# Moya-ObjectMapper response handling

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire, objectmapper

We are using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) with [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) and [Moya-ObjectMapper](https://github.com/ivanbruel/Moya-ObjectMapper), to handle the API calls.
Response from server is as below:

```
{
"userid" : "1",
"token" : "abc"
}
```

`ObjectMapper` is unable to handle this and always throws exception.

`Error info: JSONMapping(Status Code: 200, Data Length: 313)`
At the same time, it is able to handle response in this format:

```
[
{
"email":["validation.unique"]
}
]
```

I verified that the `JSON` response is in proper format. My code snippet is here:

```
struct SignupNLoginResponse: Mappable {

    var token: String?
    var userID: String?

    init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        token <- map["token"]
        userID <- map["user_id"]
    }
}

@IBAction func processSignUp () {

        SnLInput.name = "Celine Peter"
        SnLInput.email = "celine.peter@domain.in"
        SnLInput.password = "testing@123"

        provider.request(AppTarget.signUp, completion: { result in

            var success = true
            var message = "Unable to signup"

            switch result {
            case let .Success(response):
                do {
                    let outputString:NSString! = NSString(data:response.data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print(outputString)
                    if let repos: [SignupNLoginResponse]? = try response.mapObjectMapper() {
                        print(repos)
                    } else {
                        success = false
                    }
                } catch {
                    success = false
                    print("Error info: \(error)")
                }
            case let .Failure(error):
                guard let error = error as? CustomStringConvertible else {
                    break
                }
                message = error.description
            }
            print(message)
            print(success)
        })
    }
```

This is our first project using these libraries and we couldn't understand what we are missing. We appreciate any help, pointing us in the right direction. Please let know if any information found missing to figure out the issue.

Comment: Hi 
I am kind of having the same problem 
I have posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430329/moya-mapper-not-able-to-mapobjects-from-result-swift-3). If I get any help I'll post it here too.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of function did you proper method like below, maybe you're missing that.

[image: objectmapper]